# Shortest distance between two identical array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get the shortest distance between two identical array elements.

> Input [2,3,4,6,7,3,2] 
>   
>  Correct Output 4  Why? 
>   
> because int the array 3=a[1],a[5] and 5-1=4, meanwhile other identical values are far-off.
>   
>  Output Actual is 0

And this is my code.

```
int minimumDistances(vector<int> a) {
int distance=0, minDistance=(int)a.size()-1;
int prevIndex=0;
cout<<endl<<"The value ofmindistance is : "<<minDistance;
  for(int i =0; i<a.size();i++)
  {
    cout<<endl<<"The minDistance value just after entering fori : "<<minDistance;
    prevIndex=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<a.size();j++)
    {
    if(a[i]==a[j])
    {
      //cout<<endl<<"The value of i and j is :"<<i<<"and"<<j;
      cout<<endl<<"The minDistance value just after entering forj : "<<minDistance;
      //cout<<endl<<"The values of previous indices are"<<prevIndex;
      distance =j-prevIndex;
      prevIndex=j;
      cout<<endl<<"The values of previous indices are"<<prevIndex<<"The distance and mindistances are"<<distance<<","<<minDistance;
    }
    if(distance<minDistance)
    {
      minDistance = distance;
    }

  }

}
return minDistance;
}
```

**Why does minDistance become 0 after entering into the second for loop?**

Comment: Please provide your input, expected output, and actual output, including the print statements. In addition, if you could adjust your use of code indentation in your question, it will become easier to read.

Comment: Your two `if` statements should be nested, but are not. You test whether `distance<minDistance` *regardless of whether the values are equal.* And you initialize `distance` to 0, and don't give it a new value until the values *are* equal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the effect of a couple of quite ordinary bugs in the code. This question is unlikely to be of value to future readers.

Comment: But you can't telll that it is of no value, because this question is a code challenge question. And there is a high chance that this answer will be searched for. Though not with the but still the code is useful

Comment: I'd expect `minDistance=(int)a.size()-0;` instead of `minDistance=(int)a.size()-1;`  Then the calling code can determine if _any_ two identical array elements was found.  Else `[2,2]` and  `[1,2]` both return 1.

Comment: yes indeed, since the minDistance can be a.size()-1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are running

```
if(distance<minDistance)
{
      minDistance = distance;
}
```

within the inner for loop. It is being run REGARDLESS of whether `a[i]==a[j]`, so the first time the loop is run, the default value of 0 for distance will be applied to min distance regardless of the `a[i]==a[j]` check.

To fix, move this if statement within your `a[i]==a[j]` block, like so:

```
for(int j = i+1; j < a.size(); j++) {
    if(a[i]==a[j]) {
        cout<<endl<<"The minDistance value just after entering forj : "<<minDistance;
        distance = j-prevIndex;
        prevIndex = j;
        if(distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
        }
    }    
}
```